# Derivative of Mean Square Error Function with respect to output

Tags: calculus, neural-networks, mean-square-error, backpropagation

I'm trying to understand the gradient derivation for the back-propagation algorithm.

I'm having trouble computing the explicit derivative of the Loss Mean Square Error function with respect to the output value in a regression setting. I only have one output neuron.

Let,

- $n$ be the number of training examples
- $ y_i $ be the predicted target for training example $x_i$
- $ t_i $ be the actual target value (from train data) for training example $x_i$
- $ L_i $ be the loss for sample $i$

I'm using the following definition of the loss function,

$$
 E
=
 \frac{1}{2n}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}
 L_i
=
 \frac{1}{2n}
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}
 \frac{1}{2} 
 (  y_i - t_i)^2
$$

how do I compute, $\frac{\partial E}{\partial y}$ ?

This is in a neural network setting, so $E$ is a function of $w$ the weights, in the  [Bishop Book](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf) equation (5.11) is, as far as I can see, the same expression except that it's not divided by $n$,

$$ 
E(w) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n (y(x_i, w) - t_i)^2
$$
So here $y$ is a **function** which depends on $x_i$ and $w$, so writing,

$$ 
\frac{\partial E}{\partial y}
$$
means deriving by a function ??

And yet Bishop does this at equation (5.19),

$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial y_k} = y_k − t_k
$$

Where $y_k$ is the output of the kth neuron and $t_k$ the actual target value, but where are the instances gone ? They've dissapeared from the equation ! $y_k$ is predicted for an input $x$ !

I don't understand the nature of $y$ and why it's legal to derive E with respect to it.

Thanks for any help.